# Tooltip Placement - WPF

Tags: wpf

I'm trying to put together a tool tip for a simple button. However when the mouse is hovered over the button, the tool tip does not appear below it.

Please see this : [image]

This xaml is as below:

```
<Page xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      Height="300" Width="300"  xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">

    <Page.Resources>

        <Style x:Key="ToolTipStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ToolTip}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ToolTip">
                        <Grid x:Name="PopupGrid">
                            <Grid x:Name="ShadowBackground" Height="65" Width="260">
                                <Grid.Effect>
                                    <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="7" ShadowDepth="1" Opacity="0.5" />
                                </Grid.Effect>
                                <Path Margin="0 0 50 0" Width="20" Height="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Data="M0,10 L10,0 20,10Z" Stroke="Gray" Fill="#EFEFF0" Stretch="None" />
                                <Border BorderThickness="1 0 1 1" CornerRadius="3" Margin="10 9 10 10" BorderBrush="Gray" Background="#EFEFF0">
                                    <ContentPresenter/>
                                </Border>
                                <Border BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" CornerRadius="0 0 3 0" Margin="0 9 10 0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="41" Height="10" BorderBrush="Gray" />
                                <Border BorderThickness="0 1 0 0" CornerRadius="3 0 0 0" Margin="10 9 69 0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="10" BorderBrush="Gray" />

                            </Grid>                     
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ToolTipHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="ToolTipTextStyle" TargetType="{x:Type Label}">
            <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Calibri"/>
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12"/>
        </Style>

    </Page.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="PopupGrid" Background="Red">
        <Button Width="100" Height="30" Content="Click Me!">
            <Button.ToolTip>
                <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource ToolTipStyle}">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                        <Label Content="Newly Rejected" Style="{StaticResource ToolTipHeaderStyle}"></Label>
                        <Label Content="Please perform requested edits and resubmit" Style="{StaticResource ToolTipTextStyle}"></Label>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ToolTip>
            </Button.ToolTip>
        </Button>
    </Grid>

</Page>
```

I'm not sure what is causing this behavior. Can you please help to get the placement correct?

Forgot to mention how it should appear:

the triangle of the tooltip should be places right below the mouse cursor, which would mean that the tooltip should move towards left.Something like this:[image]

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: you can see this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14275755/wpf-button-with-image-trigger-mouseover-to-change-image

IsMouseOver property is not set for your case.

Comment: I'm not sure how the mouse over will solve this.

Comment: well, i never used tooltip, but what i understand is that when you mouse over the button, it should display a box. for this dont you need to trigger the mouseover event? I am not sure. hopefully some expert will clarify.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you played around with the placement properties?

You can add this to your ToolTipStyle:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.Placement" Value="Left" />
```

There's also ToolTipService.PlacementRectangle and ToolTipService.PlacementTarget

**EDIT**:

You could try:

```
<Setter Property="ToolTipService.HorizontalOffset" Value="-200" />
```

Comment: I edited my answer with another potential way to solve your issue.

Comment: However does't work when the tooltip is specified inside a datatemplate..See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451723/placement-target-binding-inside-a-datatemplate-tooltip

Comment: Glad I could help mdiehl13 ;)

Answer (score 4):

Use the CustomPopupPlacementCallback.. In my case I needed the tip to display on the right of a textbox, Placement.Right worked fine on my laptop, but was displaying to the left on my touchscreen, the easiest way to fix this is to use the callback to calculate a relative offset in the code behind:

```
...
tip.PlacementTarget = this;
tip.Placement = PlacementMode.Custom;
tip.CustomPopupPlacementCallback = new CustomPopupPlacementCallback(PositionTooltip);
...

    private CustomPopupPlacement[] PositionTooltip(Size popupSize, Size targetSize, Point offset)
    {
        double offsetY = targetSize.Height / 2 + popupSize.Height;
        double offsetX = targetSize.Width;

        return new CustomPopupPlacement[] { new CustomPopupPlacement(new Point(offsetX, offsetY), PopupPrimaryAxis.None) };
    }
```