# Placement Target Binding Inside a DataTemplate - ToolTip

Tags: wpf

In my xaml I have an Itemscontrol, which has a datatemplate set to the ItemTemplate property. Inside my datatemplate I have a button, and I have a tooltip set for the button. I'm trying to set the placement target for the tooltip to be that button, however the binding fails. Below is my code:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="MyTemplate">
<Grid x:Name="PopupGrid" Background="Red">
    <Button Width="100" Height="30" Content="Click Me!" x:Name="button">
        <Button.ToolTip>
            <ToolTip Style="{StaticResource ToolTipStyle}" PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName= button}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Content="Newly Rejected" Style="{StaticResource ToolTipHeaderStyle}"></Label>
                    <Label Content="Please perform requested edits and resubmit" Style="{StaticResource ToolTipTextStyle}"></Label>
                </StackPanel>
            </ToolTip>
        </Button.ToolTip>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

How do i specify the placement target binding to be the button?

Thanks,
-Mike

Comment: Are you sure the Binding fails? Can you paste the Binding error in your question. If i copy the code you've posted and just remove the custom `Style`'s on `ToolTip`, `Label`, it works fine. Thing is you do not even need that Binding for `PlacementTarget` to kick in when it's a direct child of `Button` anyways

Comment: for eg: if you switch one of your Label's to say `<Label Content="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Name, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ToolTip}}}" />` and remove specifying the `PlacementTarget` on the `ToolTip` element, when the app is run, you should see the label's content as "button"

Comment: So what are you expecting? You bind Label's content to the ToolTip's PlacementTarget(which is the button)'s Name(which is "button"). Shouldn't it be "button"?

Comment: @BillZhang who is your previous comment targeting? If it's me, what I'm expecting I've stated in the same comment `you should see the label's content as "button"` and I was mentioning that to show `PlacementTarget` being set implicitly even with `... remove specifying the Placementtarget on the ToolTip element ...`

Comment: @Viv, I copied your code and everything worked. What's the binding error saying?

Comment: @BillZhang err I don't have a binding error. Are you thinking I'm the person who asked this question?

Comment: @Viv, I made a mistake:), sorry for that.